# How to serialize the entire Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results.PageResult<T> object with Newtonsoft.Json in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, json, .net, odata

When I go to serialize the RageResult object with newtonsoft the serialized string contains only the data from the 'Items' property

Here is the code:

```
List<string> listString = new List<string>
{
    "Test1", 
    "Test2"
};

var pageResultTest = new PageResult<string>(listString, null, 2);
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pageResultTest, Formatting.Indented);
```

The pageResult object is serialized in this way:

```
[
  "Test1",
  "Test2"
]
```

The serialization I would expect and want to achieve is this:

```
{
  "Items": [
      "Test1",
      "Test2"
  ],
  "NextPageLink": null,
  "Count": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**PageResult** is specifically designed for Razor Page applications to produce an `IActionResult` that renders a page. It's not meant to be used as a data container for serialization purposes. That's why when you try to serialize it directly, you're not getting the expected structure in JSON.

pageResult [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pageresult?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

for the functionality you are after you will need to implement your own custom object that represents the structure you are after:

```
public class CustomPageResult<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    public string NextPageLink { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public CustomPageResult(List<T> items, string nextPageLink, int count)
    {
        Items = items;
        NextPageLink = nextPageLink;
        Count = count;
    }
}
```

Sample get api

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<CustomPageResult<string>> GetItems()
{
    List<string> items = new List<string> { "Item1", "Item2" }; // Your logic here
    string nextPageLink = null; // Your logic here
    int count = items.Count;

    var response = new CustomPageResult<string>(items, nextPageLink, count);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Than you can seriliaze:

```
List<string> listString = new List<string>
{
    "Test1", 
    "Test2"
};

var customPageResult = new CustomPageResult<string>(listString, null, 2);
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customPageResult, Formatting.Indented);
```

you will get the desired output:

```
{
  "Items": [
      "Test1",
      "Test2"
  ],
  "NextPageLink": null,
  "Count": 2
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if I have a get api that returns a PageResult<string> isn't there a way to receive in the api response the 'Count' and 'NextPageLink' properties without creating a custom class?

Comment: @Paolo It is much easier and creating a custom response class is the standard approach...
If you really want to I imagine you have to create a Custom JsonConverter
I will update my answer to include a sample Get controller action so you can integrate that to your application